# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working on asp.net core 2.2.I am using visual studio 2017.When i create the .net core web application, then interface gives an error,that current sdk does not supported targeting .net core 2.2?
And when i go to project properties, then there is not targeting framework .net core 2.2 in targeting framework lists?

Comment: So what is you problem? Simply install .net Core 2.2 SDK

Comment: Have you tried this https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-tooling-update-for-visual-studio-2017-version-15-9/

Comment: @vasily.sib  i have installed .net ccore 2.2 SDK, but it does not show in project properties targeting framework.

Comment: If you're using VS2017, make sure you use .NET Core SDK 2.2.106 or lower, as 2.2.202 and higher only work with VS2019 right now.

Comment: Thanks @KirkLarkin, 2.2.1.06 worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Install .NET Core 2.2 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2).

Note, as per Kirk's and Marc's comments, you probably need to use v2.2.106.

Comment: see Kirk's comment about versions, though - you probably want to scroll down a bit to 2.2.106

Comment: Thanks to all the guys, special thanks to @kirk Larkin ,there was a problem with .net core SDK version, 2.2.1.06 worked successfully.

Comment: @Ali: Please check this answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the working solution for this problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/470616/the-current-net-sdk-does-not-support-targeting-net-5.html)

All credit to  Vijay Ramakrishnan

> Issue details:
>   2.1.6xx & 2.2.2xx version of the sdks are only supported on Visual Studio 2019. VS 2017 needs 2.1.5xx & 2.2.1xx versions of the sdk.
>
> How to fix the issue? Install 2.1.5xx version of the SDK if you are
>   targetting a 2.1 app Install 2.2.1xx version of the SDK if you are
>   targetting a 2.2 app.
>
> You can get the install links from here -
>   https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by running the following command:

```
dotnet build
```

using command prompt within the project.

Answer (score 0):

It actually needs "2.2.1nn", where "nn" are any integers. The latest 2.2.1nn at this time is 2.2.109.  See: [Issue-3124](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3124)

```
.NET Core SDK   .NET Core Runtime   Compatible Visual Studio    MSBuild     Notes
2.1.5nn     2.1     2017    15  Installed as part of VS 2017 version 15.9
2.1.6nn     2.1     2019    16  Installed as part of VS 2019
2.2.1nn     2.2     2017    15  Installed manually
2.2.2nn     2.2     2019    16  Installed as part of VS 2019
3.0.1nn     3.0 (Preview)   2019    16  Installed manually
```

[Download .net sdk](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2)